# Change Windows Forms application icon in Add/Remove Programs

Tags: c#, winforms, icons

I have one Windows Forms application, and I deployed that using [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce). I changed the project icon. After publishing and installing, that icon is appearing on the desktop. That much is OK.

But when I search that application in Add/Remove programs in the control panel, it shows one default icon and not mine. How can I change that icon or is it not possible?

Comment: **These links** may help - `http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/e4f5bb5b-028b-481b-a7a8-ca3c2f25440e` **&**                          `http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/db1d57ee-7743-4409-8072-f0e84ab5330a`

Answer (score 0):

According to the thread in the MSDN forum, *[Missing Icon in Add/Remove Programs for ClickOnce Application](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/db1d57ee-7743-4409-8072-f0e84ab5330a)*, it seems to be possible.

Comment: Please incorporate the relevant sections of the post in your answer. If the linked page ever changes/gets deleted your answer will become useless

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure ClickOnce does not give you ability to change the icon. I use Visual Studio Setup Project in my deployment, and if you go to the Properties, the first one is 'AddRemoveProgramsIcon', where you can specify what icon you want to be used there.